# Django Design Reusable Apps?

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6, django-apps, django-1.11

I am developing `Django` application, but still have confusion over `apps` design pattern, let say my application has models like follow.

```
class Department(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

      department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

As u see student model has relation of `department = models.ForeignKey(Department)`

In This case should i need to create separate apps for `department` and `student` or  is it good enough to create `custom_app`  with both `department` and `student` models  ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create app for each model. App is more high level thing. You can logically think of app name which contains both models: for example, 'university' or 'practice' or even 'students' that will contain all the business logic of interaction with this models. Below you can create another app that could have any other models. Just try to link each model to only one app if you can

Comment: ok, since student model requires a department model, we can group into single app, if there no relation with other apps we can make it single app right?

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan yeah, for sure